# Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: implode(): Argument #2 ($array) must be of type ?array

Tags: php

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: implode(): Argument #2 ($array) must be of type ?array, string given in /home/------/imcartsend.php:25 Stack trace: #0 /home/_______/res/imcartsend.php(25): implode(';', 'Note')
> #1 {main} thrown in /home/________/imcartsend.php on line 25

on line 25

```
$imUserDataCSV = implode(";",$imUserDataCSVH) . "\n" . implode(";",
$imUserDataCSV);
```

Gives me error this error the internet page, how can we edit new php8, how can we delete the error new line.
Thank you

```
$imUserDataCSV = implode($imUserDataCSVH ";") . "\n" . implode($imUserDataCSVH ";"
);
```

always same error

Comment: Your second code block as several errors, that won't work. If you look at the error, then you'll see that `$imUserDataCSVH` is the string `Note`, not an array

Comment: To fix the error, stop your code from trying to implode strings

Answer (score 0):

You're question doesn't provide much information, but based on the error you can at least prevent it by doing the following:

```php
if (is_array($imUserDataCSVH) && is_array($imUserDataCSV)) {
    $imUserDataCSV = implode(";",$imUserDataCSVH) . "\n" . implode(";",$imUserDataCSV);
}
```

implode requires an array, so the if statement checks that the variable `$imUserDataCSVH` is an array.

Answer (score 0):

Entered but it doesn't work, the problem is solved but then it doesn't automatically send e-mails

```php
<?php
    include "imemail.inc.php";
    
    //Load content
    $PayMsg = array("S.n.c. .............");
    $imOpt = 0;
    $imOrderNo = $_POST["imOrderNo"];
    $imLocale = explode("||",$_POST["imLocale"]);
    $imUserData = str_replace("\'", "'", $_POST["imUserData"]);
    $imUserData = explode("||",$imUserData);
    $imUserDataTxt = "";
    $imUserDataHTML = "";
    $imUserDataCSVH = "";
    `$imUserDataCSV` = "";
    $i = 0;
    if(is_array($imUserData))
       foreach($imUserData as $ud) {
          $ud = explode("::",$ud);
          $imUserDataTxt .= $ud[0] . ": " . $ud[1] . "\n";
          $imUserDataHTML .= "<tr" . ($i%2 ? " bgcolor=\"#EEEEEE\"" : "") . "><td width=\"25%\"><b>" . $ud[0] . ":</b></td><td>" . $ud[1] . "</td></tr>\n";
          $imUserDataCSVH = $ud[0];
          $imUserDataCSV = $ud[1];
          $i++;
    }
    if (is_array($imUserDataCSVH) && is_array($imUserDataCSV)) {
        $imUserDataCSV = implode(";",$imUserDataCSVH) . "\n" . implode(";",$imUserDataCSV);
    }
    
    
    $imOrderData = str_replace("\'", "'", $_POST["imOrderData"]);
    $imOrderData = explode("||",$imOrderData);
    $imOrderDataTxt = "";
    $imOrderDataHTML = "";
    $imOrderDataCSV = "";
    $i = 0;
    if(is_array($imOrderData)) {
       foreach($imOrderData as $od) {
          $od = explode("::",$od);
          if(count($od) == 6)
             $imOpt = 1;
       }
       $imOrderDataHTML = "<tr bgcolor=\"#EEEEEE\"><td><b>" . $imLocale[1] . "</b></td><td><b>" . $imLocale[2] . "</b></td>" . ($imOpt ? "<td><b>" . $imLocale[3] . "</b></td>" : "") . "<td><b>" . $imLocale[4] . "</b></td><td><b>" . $imLocale[5] . "</b></td></tr>\n";
       $imOrderDataCSV = $imLocale[0] . ";" . $imLocale[1] . ";" . ($imOpt ? $imLocale[2] . ";" : "") . $imLocale[3] . ";" . $imLocale[4] . ";" . $imLocale[5];
       foreach($imOrderData as $od) {
          $od = explode("::",$od);
          switch(count($od)) {
             case 6:
                $imOrderDataCSV .= "\n" . implode(";",$od);
                $imOrderDataTxt .= $od[0] . " - " . $od[1] . " - " . $od[2] . " " . $od[3] . " x " . $od[4] . " " . $od[5] . "\n";
                $imOrderDataHTML .= "<tr" . ($i%2 ? " bgcolor=\"#EEEEEE\"" : "") . "><td>" . $od[0] . " - " . $od[1] . "</td><td>" . $od[2] . "</td><td>" . $od[3] . "</td><td>" . $od[4] . "</td><td>" . $od[5] . "</td></tr>\n";
                break;
             case 5:
                $imOrderDataCSV .= "\n" . $od[0] . ";" . $od[1] . ";" . ($imOpt ? ";" : "") . $od[2] . ";" . $od[3] . ";" . $od[4];
                $imOrderDataTxt .= $od[0] . " - " . $od[1] . " " . $od[2] . " x " . $od[3] . " " . $od[4] . "\n";
                $imOrderDataHTML .= "<tr" . ($i%2 ? " bgcolor=\"#EEEEEE\"" : "") . "><td>" . $od[0] . " - " . $od[1] . "</td>" . ($imOpt ? "<td></td>" : "") . "<td>" . $od[2] . "</td><td>" . $od[3] . "</td><td>" . $od[4] . "</td></tr>\n";
                break;
             case 2:
                $imOrderDataCSV .= "\n" . $od[0] . ";;;" . ($imOpt ? ";" : "") . ";" . $od[1];
                $imOrderDataTxt .= $od[0] . ": " . $od[1] . "\n";
                $imOrderDataHTML .= "<tr" . ($i%2 ? " bgcolor=\"#EEEEEE\"" : "") . "><td colspan=\"" . ($imOpt ? "4" : "3") . "\">" . $od[0] . "</td><td>" . $od[1] . "</td></tr>\n";
                break;
          }
          $i++;
       }
       $imOrderDataHTML .= "</table>";
    }
    
    // Template
    $htmHead = "<table width=\"90%\" border=\"0\" bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\" cellpadding=\"4\" style=\"font: 13px Tahoma; color: #000000; border: 1px solid #BBBBBB;\">";
    $htmFoot .= "</table>";
    
    //Send email to owner
    $htmMsg = $htmHead . "<tr><td><b>" . $imOrderNo . "</b></td></tr>" . $htmFoot . "<br>" . $htmHead . $imOrderDataHTML . $htmFoot . "<br>" . $htmHead . $imUserDataHTML . $htmFoot . "<br>" . $htmHead . "<tr><td style=\"font-size: 85%\"><div style=\"overflow: auto;\">" . str_replace("\n","<br>",$imOrderDataCSV) . "</div></td></tr>" . $htmFoot . "<br>" . $htmHead . "<tr><td style=\"font-size: 85%\"><div style=\"overflow: auto;\">" . str_replace("\n","<br>",$imUserDataCSV) . "</div></td></tr>" . $htmFoot;
    $oEmail = new imEMail($_POST["imUserMail"],"xxx@xxx.com",$imOrderNo,"iso-8859-1");
    $oEmail->setText($imOrderNo . "\n\n" . $imOrderDataTxt . "\n\n\n" . $imUserDataTxt . "\n\n\n" . $imOrderDataCSV . "\n\n" . $imUserDataCSV);
    $oEmail->setHTML("<html><body bgcolor=\"#063A69\" style=\"background-color: 
    #063A69\"><center>" . $htmMsg . "</center></body></html>");
    $oEmail->send();

    //Send email to user
    $htmMsg = $htmHead . "<tr><td><b>" . $imOrderNo . "</b></td></tr><tr><td>" . str_replace("\r\n","<br>",$PayMsg[$_POST["imShipment"]]) . "</td></tr>" . $htmFoot . "<br>" . $htmHead . $imOrderDataHTML . $htmFoot . "<br>" . $htmHead . 
    $imUserDataHTML . $htmFoot;
    $oEmail = new imEMail("xxx@xxx.com",$_POST["imUserMail"],$imOrderNo,"iso-8859-1");
    $oEmail->setText($imOrderNo . "\n" . $PayMsg[$_POST["imShipment"]] . "\n\n" . 
    $imOrderDataTxt . "\n\n\n" . $imUserDataTxt);
    $oEmail->setHTML("<html><body bgcolor=\"#063A69\" style=\"background-color: 
    #063A69\"><center>" . $htmMsg . "</center></body></html>");
    $oEmail->send();
    @header("Location: ../impay.html");
?>
```